# Is there a localised version of the send button for use with the send dialog?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm adding a send button for sending a link to a friend within a canvas application on a page tab:

```
            $(anchorTag).bind('click',function(e){
                //console.log($(this));
                e.preventDefault();
                      FB.ui({
                    method: 'send',
                    name:$(this).attr('title'),
                    display: 'iframe',
                    link: $(this).attr('href')
                    });

            });
```

I would like to have an icon like [image: send button] as the image for my button but I need to localise the text for different languages. Do I need to craft my own using CSS or is this button available via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of the [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and [Send Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) it has a section about different languages, but the one in the Like is a bit more detailed:

> How do I display the Like button in different languages?
>
> If you are using the XFBML version include the language code when you
>   instantiate the library. Replace ‘en_US’ in this line with the correct
>   locale code:
>
> '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
>
> If you are using the Iframe version include a locale parameter with
>   the proper country code in the src URL. Example:
>
> src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=fr_FR&..."
>
> You may need to adjust the width of the Like button to accommodate
>   different languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if it is possible to have the send popup hover above both the canvas application and the facebook 'chrome'? I have display set to 'iframe';

Comment: I'm not following you, how is it presented now and how would you like it to? maybe add screen shots to your quest?